# having some trouble and confusion in setter & @property decorator, not all attributes defined in `__init__` are updated

Tags: python, decorator, setter

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.annual_pay = 12*pay
        self.email = self.first + '.' + self.last + '@email.com'

    @property                   
    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last))

    @fullname.setter            
    def fullname(self,name):
        first,last = name.split(' ')
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

emp1 = Employee('test1','subject1',10000)
emp1.fullname='test2 subject2'
print(emp1.fullname)
print(emp1.email)
```

I used setter to assign user a fullname() and override the attributes set by **init** already on the top, but in the output it only changed fullname as test2 subject2 meanwhile email had been unchanged as test1.subject1@email.com (i learned from a tutorial and i thought we can override default attributes by this setter functionality) (Also that guy didn't use email in **init** like I did but instead he had a separate function for it with @property decorater with it)

Comment: Of course `self.email` isn't changed, you *never changed it in `fullname.setter`*. `__init__` is *entirely irrelevant*

Answer (score 3):

That is because the value of email was computed *and saved* when you ran `__init__()`. Just because you change `self.first` and `self.last` doesn't mean `self.email` will be affected, because it is not saved in terms of its relationship to those variables. It is saved as a string.

Example:

```
a = "hello"
b = "world"
c = a + b
a = "goodbye"
print(c)
>>> "hello world"
```

Here, `c` was set to `a+b` and that value was saved when that line was executed. Changing `a` after we have already given `c` its value won't change it. It is already set, and we would have to do `c = a+b` again to get it to print out `goodbye world`.

In your case, you'd have to modify it in the setter:

```
@fullname.setter            
def fullname(self,name):
    first,last = name.split(' ')
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.email = self.first + '.' + self.last + '@email.com'
```

However that is not good practice, as the setter should only change the specific variable you're accessing. That is why the tutorial you were reading had a function for email: If you want the it to be *dynamically* computed based on whatever the values of `first` and `last` are at the moment you check it, you should always use a function:

```
def email(self):
    return self.first + '.' + self.last + '@email.com'

print(emp1.email())
```

If you want, you can use the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator like the tutorial does:

```
@property
def email(self):
    return self.first + '.' + self.last + '@email.com'
```

This is just syntactical sugar to allow you to call it as before:

```
print(emp1.email)
```

Instead of having to call it like a function, even though that is all it is.

As a sidenote, I'd recommend using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting), which is generally preferred to using `+` to join strings together in cases like this:

```
return f"{self.first}.{self.last}@email.com"
```